# Behavior of closing a Virtual Machine window in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Can I set VirtualBox host to be automatically saved and closed, rather than asking me what to do for closing host window?

[image]

Comment: See my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1310797/281758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell VirtualBox to automatically save the state, or automatically power off the virtual machine when you attempt to close it.

If you're looking at the VirtualBox manager, though, and you have the machine selected, you could use one of the shortcuts (Control+V, ControlF for save/shutdown respectively) to save yourself a small amount of time.